# foreach to get the array index results in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, soap, parameters

I got the following parameters as a response from SOAP client. But i only want few to show as a result. I am getting the results properly but its only for 1 vehicle and i have more than 1 vehicles. So i dont know how to loop to get the results.

Output for 1 vehicle

```
array (size=5)
  'SchwackeCode' => int 10130969
  'WE_Number' => int 19373134
  'HSN' => string '0005' (length=4)
  'TSN' => string 'AMP' (length=3)
  'VIN' => string '12345678901472583' (length=17)
```

Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$result = $client->getVehicleValuation($params);    
$return = array(
                                    'SchwackeCode' => $result->vehicle->SchwackeCode,
                                    'WE_Number'    => $result->vehicle->WE_Number,
                                    'HSN'          => $result->vehicle->HSN, 
                                    'TSN'          => $result->vehicle->TSN,
                                    'VIN'          => $result->vehicle->Ident_Number,
                                    'WE_Number'    => $result->vehicle->WE_Number                                       
                            );
return $return;
```

Comment: Can you post your array here? I think this is output of print_r.

Comment: this is the array i used var_dump to print this ...If you can check there is Vehicle inside that there is Customer and inside that there is customer_id which i want to retrieve also the WE_Number i just have to use single statement in $return array result to get this but dont know how to get it..

Comment: do u know how to get it ?

Comment: try with this $result->Vehicle[0]->Customer[0]->WE_Number

Comment: thanks man if i do just $result->vehicle->WE_Number its running now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, then just try this simple code,

```
$cnt=0; 
$arr=Array('SchwackeCode','WE_Number','HSN','TSN' );

    foreach($result->Vehicle[$cnt]->Customer[0] as $key=>$val)
   {
         if(in_array($key,$arr)
        {
                    your_piece of code;
         }
          $cnt++;

   }
```

Didnt tested this code, but hopefully it will work. :)

Comment: hi i am sorry not running actually the code now running it will be useful for only 1 vehicle ..and what if i have more vehicles then i have to use foreach..as you said i tired but not running...Please check the updated question..

Comment: in that case you need to run one more foreach for vehicle array

Comment: just add one more loop above my code for vehicle array